# Proving a rectangle of constrained perimeter achieves a maximum area

Tags: maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

My source question comes from Vector Calculus, sixth edition by Marsden and Tromba:

> Consider all rectangles with fixed perimeter $p$. Use
> Lagrange multipliers to show that the rectangle with
> maximal area is a square.

I have shown that this indeed the case. My question is not on applying Lagrange multipliers, but that *given the perimeter constraint, there exists a maximum area rectangle.* I have shown by the bordered Hessian that the square is indeed a local maxima.

My attempt:

The objective function $h(l, w) = lw$ is bounded by $0$, attained as $l$ or $w$ tends to $p/2$. Therefore $l$ and $w$ are bounded above by $p/2$ and below by $0$. However, this constraint set is not *closed*, since the degenerate solutions of $(l,w) = (0, p/2)$ is not a rectangle, so these bounds are not in the constraint set, and I cannot cite the existence of a maxima by closedness.

Comment: You are overthinking this. Suppose you have a string tied in a loop and you want to enclose a rectangular area. Can you enclose an area that is arbitrarily large?

Comment: A degenerate rectangle is a still a rectangle, and it is perfectly valid to include it in the solution space.

Comment: Side note: this problem can be solved very simply without using Lagrange multipliers, even without any derivation. But if the goal is to learn how to use Lagrange multipliers, why not.

Comment: The problem is that at $l=0$ the function has a minimum, not a maximum. Since you know $0\le l, w\le p/2$, your maximum area **must** be less or equal to $p^2/4$. It is in fact much less. Since $h(l,w)=h(l,p/2-l)$ is a continuous function, and it's zero when $l=0$ or $l=p/2$, by mean value theorem, you have at least one maximum (or minimum) of $h$ between the two end points (and it has to be at least one maximum, since an arbitrary choice of $l$ yields a positive value of $h$).